# Joomla increase frontend session time out limit

Tags: php, session, joomla

I want to set joomla front end session to `never expire automatically`.I am thinking that session time out limit should be `45 days` so that users visiting site even after 44 days they still be logged in.I set session timeout limit in back end in the global configuration to expire in `64800 minutes` and also I updated the `session.gc_maxlifetime` to say `3888000` but still it is not working.

Joomla creates the cookie with the name `d58ba4091c622661a0d46f03b412ac8b` and expiry time says 'At end of session'.

This means that session will expire whenever a user close the browser.

Expiry time should be changed for this cookie according to configuration settings but it still say `At end of session` .

for an example how `stackoverflow session` works I need to do in same way.

Is there any way to change this cookie life time from 'At end of session' to something I want?

Should I hard code time limit where this cookie come in existences or how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this plugin:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-desk/13982

Answer (score 3):

You definitely don't want to make the session never expire because this will cause all kinds of server and security issues. You need to change the expiration of the cookie to some date in the future. The easiest way to do this would be a plugin that checks for the cookie and updates the exiration.

Comment: Please let me know if any plugin is available for this

Comment: Actually, the core Joomla login module has a "Remember Me" option that keeps the user logged in, even after the session ends.